# Sharing a third party directive in multiple angular components

Tags: angular

I am trying to use [this](https://github.com/Zak-C/ngx-loading) library in my angular 4 project which is derived from [this](https://github.com/akveo/ng2-admin) project. It works fine when I import this library's module in my component module. For example, I have a login component which has a login.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule, } from '@angular/core';
import { LoadingModule } from 'ngx-loading';
import { Login } from './login.component';


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    LoadingModule,
  ],
  declarations: [
    Login
  ]
})
export class LoginModule { }
```

**Above works perfectly fine.**

However, I don't want to import this module in every component as it creates duplicate code. Hence I created a shared module and imported the shared module in my login component's module and register component's module.

Something like this:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { LoadingModule } from 'ngx-loading';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        LoadingModule,
    ],
})

export class SharedModules {

}
```

Tried importing this in login.module:

```
import { SharedModules } from '../../sharables/shared.module';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    SharedModules,
  ],
  declarations: [
    Login
  ]
})
export class LoginModule { }
```

I have also imported SharedModules in my main app.module.

**Above throws following error:**

```
Can't bind to 'show' since it isn't a known property of 'ngx-loading'.
1. If 'ngx-loading' is an Angular component and it has 'show' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'ngx-loading' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.
```

1. **How can I achieve this in angular 4?**
2. **I would like also like to understand why this approach is not working and what am I missing here?**

Comment: From the documentation: *Getting started: Import the LoadingModule in your root application module*. Why don't you do just that?

Comment: It doesn't work. I tried doing that. I updated my answer to mention that my base project is derived from ng2-admin (https://github.com/akveo/ng2-admin)  which has a root app module and then module class for each children component. ngx-loading only works when I import it in the module class of my children component (Login module in my example)

Comment: To add on my last comment : I tried adding SharedModules in my app's root module (app.module.ts) that didn't work either.

Comment: This looks like a terrible idea. But anyway, AFAIK, this is not possible as is. LoadingModule should provide a forChild() static method that would provide everything except the service provider which should be declared in the root component using forRoot().

Comment: "This looks like a terrible idea"_____
You mean using ng2-admin with ngx-loading OR
You mean adding SharedModules in my app's root module is a terrible idea?
________________________
Also:
"AFAIK, this is not possible as is. LoadingModule should provide a forChild() static method"_______
Just so I am clear, looking at the source code for ngx-loading, you are referring that it lacks code which would allow me to achieve my use case?

Thanks

Comment: Using a separate module for each and every component looks like a terrible idea to me. And yes, I think it lacks code which would allow you to achieve your use case

Answer (score 3):

Found the answer. Thanks to [this](https://medium.com/@cyrilletuzi/understanding-angular-modules-ngmodule-and-their-scopes-81e4ed6f7407) article.

To anyone else having the same problem:

It was a scope problem. I imported the LoadingModule in my SharedModules but LoadingModule's directives were limited ONLY to the scope of SharedModules. **In order for other components (Login/Registers etc..) which are importing the SharedModules to be able to access SharedModules import (LoadingModule in this case), I must export them**.

Once I exported, LoadingModule from my SharedModules; my Login component is able to access LoadingModule's directives

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { LoadingModule } from 'ngx-loading';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        LoadingModule,
    ],
    exports: [
        LoadingModule
    ]
})

export class SharedModules {

}
```